# Show Facebook stream published feed actionlink to fans only

Tags: facebook, feed, publish, facebook-page

I created a company page, developed an app to publish feeds to that page. It works fine, but I have to find a way to show its action links only to that page's fans. I tried `Page.IsFan()` method, but it is not working, as said in docs.

I desperately need to find a way if current user viewing that feed is fan of my page and hide action links if not a fan. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible - feed stories are static content once they're published, and that includes the action links. Page.isFan is meant for API calls within an application - and works perfectly well in an application context - but you can't make API calls from within a feed story.